# How do i create a timestamp on my histogram using ggplot where time is not plotted on either axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I would like to create a timestamp on my histogram on mtcars dataset where I am plotting the frequency of mileage.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, fill="red")) + geom_histogram(bins = 30) +  
 geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(mpg)),color="blue", linetype="dashed", 
 size=1) +theme(legend.position="top")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=mpg, fill="red")) + geom_histogram(bins = 30) +  
 geom_vline(aes(xintercept=mean(mpg)),color="blue", linetype="dashed", 
 size=1) +theme(legend.position="top") +
 annotate("text", x = 30, y = 4, label = Sys.time())
```

Comment: Thank you so much , this was very helpful

Comment: No problem my friend